# stackoverflow error in following java program

Tags: java

```
public class testing {    
    testing t=new testing();                

    public static void main(String args[]){   
        testing t1=new testing();  
        t1.fun();  
    }

    void fun(){         
        int a=2;        
        int b=t.fun2(a);  
        System.out.println(a+" "+b);  
    }

    int fun2(int a)  
    {
        a=3;  
        return a;  
    }  
}
```

why does above code giving following error? I just want to know the reason because it is difficult to expect `StackOverFlowError` error in this case.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.testing.<init>(testing.java:4)
at com.testing.<init>(testing.java:4)
```

Comment: Ahh, please indent your code.  It's much easier to help you when your code is readable.

Comment: Also, classes should be capitalized.  Look up some code style guidelines.

Comment: @jack57 I know coding conventions, just written the code for quick testing. But thanx for advice anyways.

Comment: can someone provide a link where I can refer to understand because I still have some doubts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are recursively creating instance of `testing`

```
public class testing {    
 testing t=new testing();        
//

}
```

While creating first instance it will create new Instance by `testing t=new testing();` which will again create new instance and so on

Comment: I created the object for class testing and according to my understanding it will be created only once. Can you explain how multiple instances are creating?

Comment: While creating first instance it will create new Instance by `testing t=new testing();` which will again create new instance and so on

Comment: when you create the new testing() first time it is creating a object of that class but that class has new testing() and create that object and it will continue..

Comment: @JigarJoshi Still i don't understant as `public class testing { testing t=new testing(); public static void main(String args[]){ System.Out.Print("hello");}}` runs successfuly.

Comment: It is because you are not creating any instance of `testing`, once you create instance of testing it will start recursive generation, try to debug it to get the exact flow

Comment: Previously you were creating instance from main by  `testing t1=new testing();`

Comment: @user980089 What's happening is that you instantiate a `testing` object, and the first thing that happens is that this object runs all of its field initializers. In your case, the only initializer is `testing t = new testing()`, so that runs. Well, what's that do? It instantiates a `testing` object, which means all of its fields get initialized -- namely, _its_ `testing t = new testing()`. And so on. But without that first `new testing()` to get things started, none of them run -- because `testing t` is an instance variable, not a static variable, and thus only applies to new instances.

Comment: @yshavit yeah that makes sense. now i got this. thanx

Comment: @yshavit I have a doubt why this happens only in case of static methods and not in other cases .can you provide some link where i can refer to understand it completely.

Comment: @user980089 It's not only in the case of static methods, it's any time you instantiate a `testing` object. If you had some other object `FooBar` with an instance method `void baz() { new testing(); }`, invoking `myFooBar.baz()` would cause the same error.

Answer (score 1):

try this solution,

```
public class testing {                

    public static void main(String args[]){   
        testing t1=new testing();  
        t1.fun(t1);  
    }

    void fun(testing t1){         
        int a=2;        
        int b=t1.fun2(a);  
        System.out.println(a+" "+b);  
    }

    int fun2(int a)  
    {
        a=3;  
        return a;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: thanx kushan for solution, but i just want to know the reason for error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create field at class level but instantiate it once where in main

```
public class Testing {    
    static Testing t1;              

    public static void main(String args[]){   
        t1=new Testing();  
        t1.fun();  
    }

    void fun(){         
        int a=2;        
        int b=t1.fun2(a);  
        System.out.println(a+" "+b);  
    }

    int fun2(int a)  
    {
        a=3;  
        return a;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: some alternate solutions are also there which are able to elude that problem